# update all row numbers whenever there is re-order

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a list of items in an array that can be re-ordered in the view, what I want to achieve is anything there is a re-order, the `rowNumber` property should be updated from 1 to the last number

array list

```
[{
    id: 1, Name: 'Jack', rowNumber:0,
},
{
    id: 2, Name: 'Mary', rowNumber:0,
},
{
    id: 5, Name: 'Dan', rowNumber:0,
}
]
```

JS

```
 let draggedItem = this.list.splice(event.detail.from,1)[0];
 this.list.splice(event.detail.to,0,draggedItem)
event.detail.complete();
console.log(this.list.forEach(e => {
    e.rowNumber++
}))
```

currently what I'm experiencing is after a re-order is done, each of the `rowNumber` gets updated to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is incorrect. `e.rowNumber++` is not doing what you think.

How about this:

```js
const list = [
    {id: 1, Name: 'Jack', rowNumber:0},
    {id: 2, Name: 'Mary', rowNumber:0},
    {id: 5, Name: 'Dan', rowNumber:0}]
    
const ordered = list.map((e, idx) => ({...e, rowNumber: idx}))
console.log(ordered)
```

Comment: the answer starts numbering from 0, how do i make it start from 1,2,3 etc?

Comment: replace `{...e, rowNumber: idx}` with `{...e, rowNumber: idx + 1}`

Answer (score 1):

that's because you are just incrementing 0 to 1 inside each item, row numbers being stored inside each object might not be the right way of doing this - a row number is an artefact of the display or layout and perhaps should be populated when rendering items instead of storing it inside (given how transient it is). But if you wanted to do that then you could use the index of the item to assign a value to the property e.g.

```js
console.log(this.list.forEach((e, index) => {
    e.rowNumber = index
}))
```